# Interpretation of $T_1$ & $T_2$ operators in Isospin

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, isospin-symmetry

In isospin, the $T_3$ operator corresponds to whether a particle has "up" isospin, or "down" isospin, but what do the $T_1$ & $T_2$ operators correspond to then? I know we can build ladder operators out of linear combinations of them that create new isospin states, but do they have significance on their own?

A bit of background to my question: the mathematics of spin and isospin are equivalent. in traditional QM, the $S_x$ and $S_y$ operators have very obvious interpretations which is that they measure spin in the x and y directions respectively. I was thinking about how in the original isospin formulation, the proton and neutron were supposed to be different eigenstates of the $T_3$ operator. I was also thinking about how the $S_z$ component of spin commutes with the hamiltonian, meaning it is constant in time (assuming you dont measure it w.r.t. another axis and therefore create a superposition of $S_z$ states) so if you measure $S_z$ to be spin up and dont do anything to the particle, you should later measure it to still be spin up. This makes sense in the isospin state as well, that if you measure the $T_3$ component of your particle to be a neutron, you would expect it to be a neutron some later time as well. This got me thinking though about what the $T_1$ and $T_2$ operators actually represent in isospin space and if they have an analogous interpretation to "spatial" spin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well $S_1$, $S_2$, and $S_3$, which form the vector spin operator:

$${\bf S}= (S_1, S_2, S_3)$$

are all equivalent because there is no preferred direction in space. You can quantize spin about any axis you choose, and linear combination of the $S_i$, and the physics is unchanged.

The choice of the $z$-axis is entirely customary. When we do that, the operator is:

$$ S_3 = \frac{\hbar}2\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1&0\\0&-1\end{array}\right)$$

which has eigenvectors:

$$\left(\begin{array}{c} 1\\0\end{array}\right)=|\uparrow\rangle $$
$$\left(\begin{array}{c} 0\\1\end{array}\right)=|\downarrow\rangle $$

with eigenvalues $\pm\hbar/2$, respectively. Moreover, the raising and lowering operators:

$$ S_{\pm}=\frac 1 {\sqrt 2}[S_1\pm i S_2] $$

connect the two states as usual.

Now when we immerse our system in a global constant magnetic field in the $z-$direction, these states become the eigenstates of the hamiltonian.

They are the physically observable stationary states.

Isospin has the exact same mathematics. The eigenstates of the $\tau_3$ operator are $|p\rangle$ and $|n\rangle$, which are the isospin up and down states of the nucleon. Unlike spin up and down, they are not arbitrary: it is as if the universe has a global 'field' that separates the two states and makes them the observed states.

The absorption of a pion operates on these states like the $\tau_i$ operators:

$$ \tau_+|n\rangle = \frac 1{\sqrt 2}(\tau_1+i\tau_2)|n\rangle =|p\rangle \equiv \pi^++n\rightarrow p $$

$$ \tau_-|p\rangle = \frac 1{\sqrt 2}(\tau_1-i\tau_2)|p\rangle =|n\rangle \equiv \pi^-+p\rightarrow n $$

$$ \tau_3|p\rangle =|p\rangle \equiv \pi^0+p\rightarrow p $$
$$ \tau_3|n\rangle =|n\rangle \equiv \pi^0+n\rightarrow n $$

the same way the spin operators link spin eigenstates.

With that, $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ aren't really considered on their own, but the linear combination that are ladder operators are significant.

The same thing happens with spherical tensor operators, where we consider:

$${\bf e}^0 = {\bf z}$$

$${\bf e}^{\pm} = {\mp}({\bf x}\pm i{\bf y})/\sqrt 2$$

Of course $\bf x$ and $\bf y$ having meaning, but when the external field is aligned with $\bf z$ we use the spherical representation for convenience, particularly since:

$$L^2=L_x^2+L_y^2+L_z^2 =L_+L_- +L_z^2+\hbar L_z$$

is convenient for calculating amplitudes for $\langle f|L^2|i\rangle$.

Comment: Thank you for this very detailed response!